# Angularjs + Codeigniter user authentication

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have an app that has a full angularjs frontend with a codeigniter backend (with thishttps://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)

I am using the codeigniter backend just to make api requests essentially.

The problem I am having now is managing a navigation view based on whether or not a user is logged in.

I have the navigation in its own navCtrl with a userService and loginCtrl.

I am storing loggedIn true or false in a cookie with a $watch on it in the navCtrl so it will update the navigations appropriately.

Any insight on why this may not be working? Any code i need to provide to clarify? Is there a "better" way to do this?

EDIT: The $watch is not actually catching when I update the value using the userService.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a very similar setup as you. What we do is have Codeigniter send a HTTP Status code of 419 (not logged in) or something like that. And then you'll use [Angular Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors) to 'listen' for the response from the backend.

```
app.factory('loggedIn',function($q,$location){
    return {
        /*
         * Intercept all response errors & handle them
         */
        responseError: function(response) {
            if (response.status == 419) {
                console.error("You are not logged in");
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

Then push it to the $httpProvider:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('loggedIn');
}]);
```

This should handle your front-end navigation pretty easily.

There are also other things that you can do for the `$http` requests before sending & before response is returned. Makes for a slick setup.

Comment: So, you are storing your "loggedIn" using codeigniter & sessions? I will read up on the interceptors. Thank you!

Comment: Codeigniter is handling the session management. So we're just waiting for CI to tell the front end if the session isn't valid anymore. Otherwise the front end just assumes it is. If we don't get the 419 header, then we proceed with whatever we were doing.

Comment: @EnigmaRM: can you be more specific about yor code? I am new to angularjs. I am using CI and angular js. Login and Logout is totally handelled using CI only. How can I check sessions using angular js? I have session as two-dimensional  array. Like: `$_SESSION['user_data']['id'] , $_SESSION['user_data']['role'], $_SESSION['user_data']['username'] `

Comment: Javascript can not check `$_SESSION` variables. For every AJAX request that was made to the backend, there was a function to check if it was a valid session & the user is still logged in. CI handled the real authentication for each request. If they were not logged in, an HTTP status code of 419 was sent to the front end. Per: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes, 419 means Authentication Timed Out. But you could use whatever error code you want. Then the code above will detect  if a 419 is sent for ANY ajax request.

Comment: @EnigmaRM: I have written answer for this question. And the same I am using to check loggedIn status and Role of User. What I am doing is: Written javascript function `check_session()` which requests the status from BACKEND using AJAX. I am getting response 1 if error(not logged in or not authorized). If response is 1 I am just redirecting to LOGIN page (which is not in angular js). Is this better way? I need to call `check_session()` wherever I need. So if I forgot to call this function, security becomes weak!

Answer (score 0):

**Checking sessions in Angularjs and CI using AJAX:**

Javascript function called in angular js controllers:

```
 function check_session()
    {
        $.get(base_url+"admin/check_session/check", function(data, status){
             if(data=="1") /* error 1 => un-athorized user */
            {
                window.location.href=base_url+"login";
            }
            });
    }
```

**Expaining AJAX request:**
*check_session* is CI controller and *check* is function in that.